# Segmentation fault -- Alphabetically sorting a list

Tags: list, segmentation-fault, alphabetical-sort

I was given a file with several recipes denoted at the beginning by 0. Each recipe is followed by it's ingredients denoted at the beginning by 1 as shown below :

`char *rawRecipes[]={
"0Broccoli Coleslaw",
"1olive oil",
"1white vinegar",
"1white sugar",
"1package chicken flavored ramen noodles",
"1broccoli",
"1carrots",
"1green onions",
"1sunflower seeds",
"0Creamy Broccoli Salad",
"1broccoli",
"1red onion",`

I'm trying to alphabetically sort the ingredients in a list, but I'm getting segmentation fault. I would greatly appreciate your help on this. Here is what I've done:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int input; 
    printf("\n"); 
    printf("\n"); 
    printf("Enter a command by number\n");
    printf("4. List All Ingredients in alphabetical order\n"); 
    printf("Give input: "); 
    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input == 4) //  List All Ingredients in alphabetical order
    { 
        int i = 0,k;
        char alphabet[1000] ; 
        while(strcmp(rawRecipes[i], "") !=0)
            {
                if(rawRecipes[i][0] == 1 && rawRecipes[i+1][0] == 1)
                {
                    char temp;
                    for(k=0; k<250; k++)
                  { 
                        alphabet[k] = rawRecipes[i]; 
                        alphabet[k + 1] = rawRecipes[i + 1];
                  }
                        if(strcmp(alphabet[i], alphabet[i + 1] > 0))
                            {
                                temp = alphabet[i]; 
                                strcpy(alphabet[i], alphabet[i + 1]); 
                                strcpy(alphabet[i + 1], temp);
                            }
                }
                i++;
            } 

            int m;
            for(m=0; m < 250; m++)
            {
                        printf("%d: %c", m, alphabet[m]); 
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't provide a *picture* of your code (which is useless). Instead, edit your question and paste your *entire* code into it.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
        int i,k;
        char alphabet[1000] ; 
        while(strcmp(rawRecipes[i], "") !=0)
```

What do you expect the value of `i` to be?

That value is undefined, and could be 0, -10000, or 10000000. Some of the possible values will cause immediate crash right on the first iteration through the loop, while trying to construct an argument to `strcmp` (due to `i` being out of range for access to `rawRecipes`).

You probably want: `int i = 0, k;`.

There are other bugs as well.

You should really learn how to use a debugger, and [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

And before debugging, you should turn on compiler warnings, and fix all of the bugs compiler will tell you about.

Here is one from GCC:

```
t.c:41:37: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   41 |                         alphabet[k] = rawRecipes[i];
```

Comment: Hi @EmployedRussian, yes I tried fixing them, but I didn't know if what I was doing was correct because of the segmentation fault. I included i =0 in my code and still get segmentation fault.

Comment: do you know how I can fix the error that you showed in your comment?

Comment: @unicorns101 I do. You need to think about what you are given, and what you are doing. You have set of *pointers* (to strings), and you need re-order these pointers. Hint: `strcpy` should not even appear in your solution.